# Racket GUI: how to reference widgets created dynamically during the runtime?

Tags: racket

This is the first time I use Racket GUI and I must say that I feel really confused.

I have these requirements:

1. a window composed of several widgets
2. the widgets state must change with user actions
3. it is possible to have several instances of these windows in the same time

Because of (3), I created a function `create-window` which create a new window with the new widgets.
But because of this, I have no global variable to reference my widgets.

How to reference widgets created dynamically during the runtime?

How to organize the GUI code in an idiomatic Racket GUI style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where the reference needs to occur. Who needs to talk to whom?

For example, if one widget has a callback to another widget in the same frame, and if you're creating both widgets together, then you can just name them and have the callback closure refer to the right name (ie, variable). Here's a little example program:

```
#lang racket/gui

;; create-hello-window : -> Void
(define (create-hello-window)
  (define f (new frame% (label "Example") (width 600) (height 400)))
  (define t (new text%))
  (define ec (new editor-canvas% (parent f) (editor t)))
  (define b (new button% (parent f) (label "Say hello")
                 (callback (lambda (b ce) (say-hello t)))))
  (send f show #t)
  (void))

;; say-hello : Editor -> Void
(define (say-hello t)
  (send t set-position (send t last-position))
  (send t insert "Hello world!\n"))

;; Create two independent hello windows
(for ([i 2]) (create-hello-window))
```

Notice that the button callback refers to the local variable `t` (the editor).

For more complicated communication, you need to save references somewhere to the objects you want to refer to. Here's another version of the previous program, where the windows are organized into groups, and each window has a button that writes a greeting to the other windows in the group. The group manages a list of windows and their editors.

```
#lang racket/gui

;; A HelloWin is (hellowin Editor Frame)
(struct hellowin (editor frame))

;; A HelloGroup is (hellogroup String (Listof HelloWin))
(struct hellogroup (name [wins #:mutable]))

;; create-hello-window : HelloGroup -> Void
(define (create-hello-window group)
  (define f
    (new frame% (label (hellogroup-name group)) (width 600) (height 400)))
  (define t (new text%))
  (define ec (new editor-canvas% (parent f) (editor t)))
  (define hi-b
    (new button% (parent f) (label "Say hello")
         (callback (lambda (b ce) (add-to-end t "Hello world!\n")))))
  (define greet-b
    (new button% (parent f) (label "Greet others in group")
         (callback (lambda (b ce) (greet-everyone-else t group)))))
  (send f show #t)
  (set-hellogroup-wins! group (cons (hellowin t f) (hellogroup-wins group))))

;; add-to-end : Editor String -> Void
(define (add-to-end t str)
  (send t set-position (send t last-position))
  (send t insert str))

;; greet-everyone-else : Editor HelloGroup -> Void
(define (greet-everyone-else my-t group)
  (for ([h (in-list (hellogroup-wins group))])
    (define t (hellowin-editor h))
    (unless (equal? t my-t)
      (add-to-end t (format "~a, hello from another window!\n"
                            (hellogroup-name group))))))

;; Create two groups, and create windows for each group.

(define group1 (hellogroup "Group 1" null))
(for ([i 3]) (create-hello-window group1))

(define group2 (hellogroup "Group 2" null))
(for ([i 2]) (create-hello-window group2))
```

My code doesn't use `hellowin-frame`, but you could use it to write a procedure that closes all of the windows in a group, for example.

Maybe you don't want the group to have direct access to the frame and its widgets. Then you could change the protocol so that groups contain some sort of greeting callbacks, or an object (not the widget itself) implementing a `greetable<%>` interface that you define, or so on. Then the callback (or `greetable<%>` object) will have references (or fields) to the widgets but not expose them directly to the group code. Also, maybe a group should be an object with a registration method instead of a struct with a mutable field.

Comment: Your examples are very helpful! Thank you.